# Content script can connect to background script but popup.js cannot connect to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

In my code, I currently have a content script that sends a message to a background script, and in response creates an alert. This works for `example.js` and `background.js` when visiting `https://www.google.com`. However, when trying to establish communication between `popup.js` and my content script, I get the error message

```
Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

What I currently have is I send a message from popup.js once a button on the popup is clicked on. Then, a console message should be displayed from the content script, `example.js`, but it doesn't even seem to be reaching the content script's listener. Here's the code,

popup.js:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('highlight').addEventListener('click', sendHighlightMessage, false);
}

function sendHighlightMessage() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log("going through tabs " + tabs[0].url); //this actually occurs

      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {highlight: true}, function(response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          // An error occurred :(
          console.log("ERROR: ", chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        else{
          console.log(response.message);
        }
      });
  });  
}
```

example.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Hello World');
chrome.tabs.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log("received " + response); //never gets to this point
  sendResponse({message : "Response Received"});
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
  alert(response);
});
chrome.tabs.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
 console.log("received " + response);
 sendResponse({message : "Response Received"});
});
```

I've tried a lot of answers but none have seem to worked so far.

Comment: `doesn't even seem to be reaching` what do you mean by `seem`? You have a debugger in devtools to know exactly what happens. Set a breakpoint in the content script listener (devtools - Sources panel - content scrips), then open devtools for the popup and step through the code or set breakpoints. This shouldn't take more than a minute.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have the same exact issue.  Sending msg from popup to background. Set breakpoints, wherever possible. Symptoms just like OPs:

```console.log("going through tabs " + tabs[0].url); //this actually occurs

and  

``` chrome.tabs.sendMessage

doesn't occur

Comment: EDIT: turns out the issue was getting a response back from background.js. So,  

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
  alert(response);
  sendResponse({msg:'allgood'})
});

So alert(response) works fine, but sendResponse callback that supposed to sent msg:allgood from background.js to popup.js is not doing its job.

Answer (score -3):

Popups scripts were designed not to be able to talk to content scripts directly, you have to send messages through the background script to accomplish this.

Have your popup send the message to the background page first, have the background page send another message to specific content script. Have your content script listen for the event from the background page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried following what you said by basically adding the same listener to `background.js` (check the edit for clarity) but I can't seem to get a connection between the background script and `popup.js` either.

Comment: `Popups scripts were designed not to be able to talk to content scripts directly` - this is not true. Popup script can communicate with content scrips directly **when the popup is shown**.